# Class Logic Not Returning Value

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-2012

I have some code written in C#. My class is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DrivetimeFileDump
{
public class DriveTimeObject
{

    public decimal? _Parts;

    public decimal? Parts
    {           
        get { return _Parts; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _Parts = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _Parts = 0.00M;
            }
        }       
    }

    public decimal? GetAmountChargedParts(string ComponentStatus) 
    {
        string[] ComponentStatuses = new string[] { "i", "n", "d", "w", "e", "v" };
        foreach (var item in ComponentStatuses) 
        {
            if (item == ComponentStatus)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        return _Parts;
    }
```

I've taken out the working code to make it easier to read. I then use Entity Framework to gather a list of items.

```
 DriveTimeObject DT = new DriveTimeObject();
 DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

 DataQuery = (from z in dd.viewDriveTimeFileDump_V2 where z.dtmReported <= today select z).ToList();
```

I loop through each item and then call a method to give parts a value below.

```
 foreach (var item in DataQuery) 
        {
            decimal? AmountChargedParts = DT.GetAmountChargedParts(item.chrComponSts);


            DataFile.Add( new DriveTimeObject
            {

            Parts = AmountChargedParts,

            });

        }
```

Everything seems to be flowing, but when the value gets set, it is getting set to null when i need it to be getting set to 0.00. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Check if decimal? Is null and set it to 0.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` block, you are setting `Parts` for the `DriverTimeObject` that is being created, but you never seem to set `DT.Parts`.  So, each time you call `DT.GetAmountChargedParts`, and it can't find a matching `ComponentStatus`, it will return `_Parts` (for the current instance: DT), which will always be null.

Comment: When i return _Parts, shouldn't it be checking to see if it is null and if it is it would then return 0.00?

Comment: So close.  In `GetAmountChargedParts` you are returning `_Parts` instead of `.Parts`.  In the property `.Parts`, you also return the unchecked `_Parts`.  For `DT` you never call the setter, so `DT.Parts` and `DT.GetAmountChargedParts` always return null.